# Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Tags: php, ооп

При попытке присвоить переменной класс получаю ошибку. Я только начинаю прошариваться в ООП, так что не знаю, что делаю не так

```
class SendMessage
{
    public $chatid = '';
    public $message ='';

    //Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in /file on line 7
    public $connection = new MakeConnection();

    public function SendTextMessage() {
        $connection->method = "sendMessage?chat_id=".$this->chatid.'&text='.$this->message;
        return $connection->ReturnConnection();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написано же, что нельзя так делать `public $connection = new MakeConnection();`

Задавай значение в конструкторе.